# Python access parseargs from other class

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is an executable main.py file who takes as argument a savefile, how can I check in an other class if the savefile was given over?

code main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test")
  parser.add_argument('--savefile', help="A savefile")
  args = parser.parse_args()


if(args.savefile):
    from A import A
    a = A()
    a.run() //executes the run function in A
```

class A.py

```
class A(){
   def run():
      import main
      if(main.args.savefile):
        //do sth
}
```

However I always seem to get the AttributeError: `module 'main' has no attribute 'args'`

Appreciate any help, ty.

Comment: why not giving `args` to the class as a parameter when you instantiate it ?

Comment: What do you really want to accomplish ?  Can you say it in english?  Because, import main following by main.args.savefile will never work.  There is no method nor variable named 'args' in main.py

Comment: @SamirSadek oh ok, I just want to be able to get the savefile which is in args, (the main file is getting called via cli)

Comment: (please correct the syntax in the class, it doesn't look like python)

Comment: Then just pass it as argument to the run.   2 if(args.savefile):¬                                                                                                                
  0     a = A()¬                                                                    
  1     a.run(ags.savefile) ¬

Comment: @SamirSadek it worths an answer

Comment: Thank you PRMoureu but my answer almost the same than you.  I would have only passed the argument to run() as it seems to be optional and like that I would have save the _init__()

Comment: it's shorter, could be better if the class doesn't use it elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following pattern to avoid dangerous imports.

The main change is in the class, where we declare the `__init__` function to accept the parameter we will give in the `main` file.

```
#file A.py
class A():
    def __init__(self, savefile=None):
        self.savefile = savefile

    def run(self):    
        if self.savefile:
            # do sth
            print(self.savefile)
```

---

```
# main.py
import argparse
from A import A

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test")
    parser.add_argument('--savefile', help="A savefile")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.savefile:
        a = A(args.savefile)
        a.run()
```